# Turtlebot not moving

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a newbie and running Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04, gazebo 2.2.3.
I'm working on the tutorial and got some errors.

Command

```
$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

Here are errors.

```
 [FATAL] [1515488958.125011231, 0.130000000]: Failed to load nodelet '/cmd_vel_mux` of type `yocs_cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet` to manager `mobile_base_nodelet_manager'
    [FATAL] [1515488958.139058732, 0.140000000]: Failed to load nodelet '/depthimage_to_laserscan` of type `depthimage_to_laserscan/DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet` to manager `laserscan_nodelet_manager'
```

gazebo gui shows up but turtlebot won't move.

Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279219/turtlebot-not-moving/) by [uclaxx99](https://answers.ros.org/users/33210/uclaxx99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-10**:
What is this a duplicate of?

It seems like you resolved your own question. Would accepting your own answer not be better in that case?

**Comment by [uclaxx99](https://answers.ros.org/users/33210/uclaxx99/) on 2018-01-10**:
Sorry my mistake.
As you suggest, I'd like to change the reason. but I can't reopen for short points.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-10**:
I've just re-opened it for you.

No need to 'change the reason': just tick the checkmark to the left of your own answer to answer your own question.

We don't close questions here on ROS Answers if they have an answer.

**Comment by [uclaxx99](https://answers.ros.org/users/33210/uclaxx99/) on 2018-01-10**:
Thank you gvdhoorn!
I did it but I got another error..

> 10 points required to accept or unaccept your own answer

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-10**:
I've accepted it for you.

**Comment by [uclaxx99](https://answers.ros.org/users/33210/uclaxx99/) on 2018-01-10**:
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've found a solution by myself.
Here's what I did.

Command

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-yocs*
```

Now it looks fine.

---

Originally posted by [uclaxx99](https://answers.ros.org/users/33210/uclaxx99/) with karma: 36 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2